# Add CC and BCC when composing an email with mu4e

Tags: mu4e, message-mode

If I compose an email with mu4e I can only enter a recipient in the `TO:` field. But there are no fields for `CC` (carbon copy) and `BCC` (blind carbon copy). How can I use those fields?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look in the Field Menu  and select those fields. For me, the key shortcuts are `C-c C-f C-c` (`message-goto-cc`) for CC and `C-c C-f C-b` (`message-goto-bcc`) for BCC. These will add those fields.

Alternatively, I think you can just type them in yourself in the header, e.g. after the To: line, press enter, type Cc: and a space then add the email address you want.

Comment: yes, just typing the fields in manually works fine. Once you add the CC: mu4e knows to offer address completion. I didn't know there were shortcuts to do this!

Answer (score 1):

You can automate like this (based on http://www.djcbsoftware.nl/code/mu/mu4e/Compose-hooks.html).

```emacs-lisp
  ;; Always BCC myself
  ;; http://www.djcbsoftware.nl/code/mu/mu4e/Compose-hooks.html
  (defun my-add-header ()
    "Add CC: and Bcc: to myself header."
    (save-excursion (message-add-header
                     (concat "CC: " "\n")
                     ;; pre hook above changes user-mail-address.
                     (concat "Bcc: " user-mail-address "\n"))))
  (add-hook 'mu4e-compose-mode-hook 'my-add-header)
```